# Child component display data changes realtime while typing in another child component (form)

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app using context api and hooks managing the global state, which pulls data from a database. One child component (a sidebar) displaying data changes realtime while typing in another child component (a form). Is this expected or a bug?

I used context api and hooks to manage the state . since I have many fields in the form, I used useReduce and a mapping for onChange as showing below

```
const InfoContext = React.createContext();

let reducer = (info, newInfo) => {
  if (newInfo === null) {
    localStorage.removeItem("info");
    return initialState;
  }
  return {
    ...info,
    ...newInfo
  };
}

const initialState = {}

const InfoProvider = (props) => {
const [info, setInfo] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  const onChange = key => e => {
    setInfo({
      [key]: e.target.value
    });
  }
```

expect onChange only change the fields while typing in the forms. Data displaying in other child components will change after onSubmit is successful and database is updated.

Comment: I think it is expected behaviour. You can maintain a state for form submit and use that in other component to display your field value

Comment: @ravibagul91 thanks for the comments! Not sure about the solution here, how do I maintain the make the display data change only after I press submit and updated the database?